# How I can get the Array Element from the Array?

Tags: php, oop, smarty

I have a Problem with my Own class.

```
FileHandler::getFileInfo($_FILES["datei"])
```

return this Array:

```
Array ( [tmp_name] => D:\xampp\tmp\phpD1C1.tmp [size] => 0.01 [type] => text/plain [error] => 0 [name] => witze.txt )
```

I want to Assign the "[error] => 0" to my Template in "public function assignVariables()" But it doesn't work.

What can I do to solve the problem?

My class:

```
<?php
// Imports von den Klassen die benötigt werden
require_once(INCLUDE_PATH . 'smarty/Smarty.class.php');
require_once(CLASS_PATH . 'database.class.php');
require_once(CLASS_PATH . 'FileHandler.class.php');

class IndexPage extends Smarty {
    public $templateName = 'index.tpl';
    public $query = null;
    public $fileError = array();
    public $sql = array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->template_dir = TEMPLATE_PATH;
        $this->compile_dir = COMPILE_DIR;
        $this->config_dir = CONFIG_DIR;
        $this->cache_dir = CACHE_DIR; 

        $this->assignVariables();
        $this->returnInfos();
        $this->showTemplate($this->templateName);
    }

    public function saveData() {

    }

    public function returnInfos() {
        if(isset($_FILES["datei"])) {
            $fileError = FileHandler::getFileInfo($_FILES["datei"]);
        }
    }

    public function assignVariables() {
        print_r($fileError);
        echo $fileError["error"];
        $this->fileError["error"];
        self::assign(
            array(
                "array" => array(1,2,3,4),
                "error" => $this->fileError["error"],
            )
        );
    }

    public function showTemplate($template) {
        self::display($template);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You never actually assigned `$this->fileError`. You assigned a local var `$fileError` in `returnInfos()`, but in `assignVariables()` you have a no-op `$this->fileError['error'];` without any assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. First is in the constructor. The `returnInfos` method should be called before the `assignVariables` method.

The second problem: you use local variables instead of properties. Those methods should look like this:

```
public function returnInfos() {
    if(isset($_FILES["datei"])) {
        $this->fileError = FileHandler::getFileInfo($_FILES["datei"]);
    }
}

public function assignVariables() {
    print_r($this->fileError);
    $this->fileError["error"];
    self::assign(
        array(
            "array" => array(1,2,3,4),
            "error" => $this->fileError["error"],
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: works great thanks. The problem was in my template {$error.1} :/

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning FileHandler::getFileInfo($_FILES["datei"]); to a local variable $fileError in returnInfos() that isn't accessible from assignVariables().  From that code I don't see where $this->fileError is being set

Answer (score 0):

**option one :**  in `returnInfos()` replace `$fileError` with `$this->fileError` or

**option two :** make the assignment in `returnInfos()`